# Googletranslator in azure function

Tags: azure, function

I'm seeking a solution involving an Azure Function written in Python. This function should retrieve data from an Azure SQL table, utilize the Google Translate API to translate the content of the 'verbatim' column, and then update the same 'verbatim' column with the translated text in English

Comment: are you facing a certain challenge/issue with your approach? I would assume you call the translate API with your text as payload? https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/basic/translating-text#translate_translate_text-python

Answer (score 0):

In order to query your SQL result in your Python Function use the code below, I have used pyodbc module to connect my Azure Functions with SQL and got the results with by querying Select statement inside the code like below:-

**`My init.py to get the query results:-`**

```py
import logging
import pyodbc
import os
import azure.functions as func
import json

def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')
    
    connectionstring = os.environ["connectionstring"]
    conn = pyodbc.connect(connectionstring)
    cursor = conn.cursor()
  
    response = cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM Products")
    
    # Fetch all rows and store them in a list of dictionaries
    rows = [dict(zip([column[0] for column in cursor.description], row)) for row in response]
    
    conn.commit()
    cursor.close()
    conn.close()

    # Serialize the rows as JSON and return as the response body
    return func.HttpResponse(
        body=json.dumps(rows),
        mimetype="application/json",
        status_code=200
    )
```

**My local.settings.json:-**

```json
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "python",
    "connectionstring": "DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};SERVER=tcp:siliconsqlserver76.database.windows.net;PORT=1433;DATABASE=silicondb76;UID=siliconuser;PWD=xxxxxx"
    
  }
}
```

**Output:-**

[image]

Now, In order to translate this query results via [**google translation document**](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/basic/translating-text#translate_translate_text-python) code given by Juilian Huppauff and utilize it in your Functions code like below:-

**`init.py with Google translation:-`**

```py
import logging
import pyodbc
import os
import azure.functions as func
import json

def translate_text(target: str, text: str) -> dict:
   
    from google.cloud import translate_v2 as translate

    translate_client = translate.Client()

    if isinstance(text, bytes):
        text = text.decode("utf-8")

   
    result = translate_client.translate(text, target_language=target)

    print("Text: {}".format(result["input"]))
    print("Translation: {}".format(result["translatedText"]))
    print("Detected source language: {}".format(result["detectedSourceLanguage"]))

    return result

def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')
    
    connectionstring = os.environ["connectionstring"]
    conn = pyodbc.connect(connectionstring)
    cursor = conn.cursor()
  
    response = cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM Products")
    
    # Fetch all rows and store them in a list of dictionaries
    rows = [dict(zip([column[0] for column in cursor.description], row)) for row in response]
    
    conn.commit()
    cursor.close()
    conn.close()

    # Translate each row's text field and add translations to the rows
    target_language = "fr"  # Change this to your desired target language
    for row in rows:
        if "text" in row:
            translation_result = translate_text(target_language, row["text"])
            row["translated_text"] = translation_result["translatedText"]

    # Serialize the rows as JSON and return as the response body
    return func.HttpResponse(
        body=json.dumps(rows),
        mimetype="application/json",
        status_code=200
    )
```